# How do I use evaluate property for an object in LogicApp?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need following expression to use value of variable called `StateTagName` instead of hardcoded value of `CurrentEastUSHDInsightsObject`. How do I do that?

```
{
    "inputs": "@json(variables('CurrentTags').CurrentEastUSHDInsightsObject)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is not to use dot notation but square brackets
`json(variables('CurrentTags')[variables('StateTagName')])`